# New to Scheme, stuck on this one

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

write a scheme function `workit` that takes a predicate and a list of integers as arguments. the function should multiply each item in the list that satisfies the predicate by 2 and adds the results. For example::

```
(workit even? '(1 2 3 4 5 6)) ==> 4+8+12=24
(workit odd? '(1 2 3 4 5 6)) ==> 2+6+10=18
```

You may not use `map`, `remove`, `filter`, or any other higher order function.

Could someone at least help me get a head start on this? Decided to learn Scheme for a job that I am interested in applying for.... Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: How's your Javascript? Or any other functional programming? Have you looked at the patterns of recursive function definitions in Scheme? Can you identify what you're unclear on at this point?

Comment: Also, if your goal is to learn scheme (to some first approximation) you will get a lot of bang for your buck working through [The Little Schemer](http://amzn.to/1ktFC8R)

Comment: Free books: [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) and [HtDP](http://www.htdp.org).

Comment: Both excellent and highly recommended! Li'l Schemer has the advantage of being consumable in around 3 hours, but SICP and HtDP are far more comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

First define `even?`

```
(define (even? x) (= 0 (modulo x 2)))
```

You can define `odd?` in terms of *not* even

```
(define (odd? x) (not (even? x)))
```

Your `workit` function is pretty self-explanatory

```
(define (workit predicate xs)
  (define (iter sum xs)
    (cond ((empty? xs) sum)
          ((predicate (first xs)) (iter (+ sum (* 2 (first xs))) (rest xs)))
          (else (iter sum (rest xs)))))
  (iter 0 xs))
```

I defined an inner `iter` function to step through the list of provided numbers, `xs`, while keeping track of the output, `sum`.

- If the list we're iterating through is `empty?`, we're done, so return the `sum`
- Else, if `(predicate x)` is true, add `(* 2 x)` to the `sum` and continue iteration
- Otherwise, the predicate is false, do not alter the sum for this iteration

I chose to use the auxiliary `iter` function in order to achieve proper [tail recursion](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Lists__Iteration__and_Recursion.html#(part._tail-recursion)). This allows `workit` to operate in constant space.

---

Outputs

```
(print (workit even? '(1 2 3 4 5 6))) ;; => 24

(print (workit odd? '(1 2 3 4 5 6)))  ;; => 18
```

Answer (score 0):

- If there are no elements in the list, the workit of the list is some base
  value.
- If the first element satisfies some condition, then the workit of the list is the result of some operation involving that first element, and the workit of the remainder of the list.
- If the first element does not satisfy the condition, then the workit of the list is simply the workit of the remainder of the list.

Note that each time workit is called recursively (as in the second and third cases) the list is the remainder of the list in the the previous call.